# mysql connect_error not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I have database class as under

```
class Database {

private $db_link;
private $db_host;
private $db_user;
private $db_password;
private $database_name;

public function __construct($filename){

include ("include/".$filename);

$this->db_link = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password);

if($this->db_link->connect_error){

throw new Exception("Database is not available. ".$this->db_link->connect_errno);
}
```

The question is the if block is not executing even I put the wrong details to connect with mysql database...please point out if i am addressing it wrong as I am new to OOP

```
try{
$db = new Database($filename);

echo "connected";
}

catch(Exception $e){
echo "message: ".$e->getMessage();
exit();
}
```

Comment: How are you testing your class?

Comment: Also note that: **The `mysqli->connect_error` property only works properly as of PHP versions 5.2.9 and 5.3.0. Use the `mysqli_connect_error()` function if compatibility with earlier PHP versions is required.**

Comment: Are you sure that the filename is `vars.inc` and not `vars.inc.php` or something else? Are the variables global? Replace `include` with `require`

Comment: There is no issue with vars.inc as I set them and tested within the Database class using echo $this->db_user = $db_user;